# nogui is not working in dbisql using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sybase, powershell-3.0, sqlanywhere

I need to execute the sql file in powershell. I am using dbisql command to execute the file with its parameter

```
& 'C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64\dbisql.exe' -q -c $credential -onerror exit READ $querypath "FBM786"
```

This is the command working fine but this is not closing the interactive window. For that i have used -nogui but it is not working & no error message also that command i have given below

```
& 'C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\bin64\dbisql.exe' -nogui -q -c $credential -onerror continue READ $querypath "FBM786"
```

Comment: try `start-process` with -nonewwindow parameter...may work

Comment: How to Start-process here. i am not using any batch files in powershell

Comment: `start-process notepad -windowstyle Hidden`... or -nonewwindow...check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx

Comment: I think, this is for batch files but i am not using any batch files here

Comment: you probably havent read the link i gave you...anyway this will be my last comment... `start-process` is a powershell cmdlet that you use in powershell not batch files...good luck

Answer (score 0):

'Batch scripts should call dbisql or dbisql.com, not dbisql.exe. The dbisql.com executable is linked as a console application.'
http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbadmin/dbisql-interactive-dbutilities.html